# How to add 'title' attributes to breadcrumbs links?

Tags: navigation, breadcrumbs

I'm currently using Crumbs module for creating breadcrumbs on my website. I added 'short title' field to nodes and show its content in breadcrumbs instead of much longer node titles. This makes breadcrumbs shorter and much prettier however it is sometimes difficult for users to understand links destinations as I often use abbreviations as 'short titles'. Would be nice to add the full node titles to the breadcrumbs' links (they will be shown on hover as a guide for users). I haven't found any solutions to achieve this so far. Any ideas?

Comment: template_breadcrumb

Comment: Namari, could you please be a little more specific? :)

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/239335
for obscure reasons the hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter doesn't want to display the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter().
I think it is

```
$item['localized_options']['attributes']['title'] = 'The title';
```

Play around and report here if this works!

It is called from crumbs_CurrentPageInfo::breadcrumbItems(), with some useful data with each trail item.

However, this added data is only available if Crumbs is active. Your module with the hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter() implementation may no longer work correctly if you disable Crumbs.

Comment: At one time I had the idea to introduce a findLinkTitle() plugin method similar to the findTitle() and findParent() methods. But I figured that there are not going to be as many different plugins that define a link title attribute, so we don't need all the hierarchical prioritization stuff.